# Ten percent of the brain myth - What would happen?

Tags: futurology, psychology

The science disproved, that the Ten percent of the brain myth is true.
What do you think would happen, if it would really be true and you could expand the capacity of brain usage to 100%?

At the moment we can control parts of our own body functions after a high amount of training. What will happen behind the 10%? Will there be things like Psy-Powers or not?

Yes, the question is based on the movie "Lucy", but it had some logical fails and I want to find new possibilities!

Comment: Do you mean that I'm only my sub-conscious right now? Our brain is a energy efficient organic organ and utilize approximately 20% of energy in our body, it do not "idle" unless there is a damage took to the brain either deliberate or not resulting in more neuron's death. It is so efficient that we can perform best when focusing on one thing at a time, things get messy when multitasking. Expand the capacity of brain usage to 100%, I can arrange a interview session with a conjoined twin, give me your schedule.

Comment: Your question seems a bit on the broad side... could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I didn't mean it as idle. I mean that if we go at our maximum, all we can use is 10%. The rest of the brain isn't accessible for the human. What would be if we can use the other 90% too. Could we control more than our own bodyfunctions? Maybe external things like a stone or even other creatures?

Comment: The trick with the "10%" is that it's not entirely untrue. We are only using about 10% of our brain... at a time. First, there's absolutely no need to access all the deepest-buried memories and most obscure skills all of the time - we access them when we need to. And then, it would quickly overheat, it would use up more oxygen and nutrients than blood is able to provide, and the resulting overload would be quite counter-productive. There is just one situation in human life where 100% of the brain is active: when receiving electro-shocks.

Comment: We are using more than 10% at a time. Scientists made tests in different situations, and the whole brain (sure not all parts to 100%) was active!

Comment: I'm putting this question on hold for the moment. There are at this point primarily two things I'd want to see fixed with it. (1) Clarify in the question what the "ten percent of the brain myth" states, for those of us who are not familiar with the concept. (2) I find the first sentence of the question rather confusing, and would encourage you to look at it again and perhaps clarify it. What are you suggesting scientists to have proved or disproved? Note: please **[edit]** the question to include additional clarification; do not respond in comments. Editing will nominate this for reopening.

Comment: we use 100% of the brain all the time, we use it to be conscious, to stay alive, to regulate temperature, to regulate all the organs on the body, to move and to process senses into information... If you used only 10% of the brain you would be pretty much dead.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if by 'use 10% of the brain', you mean only 10% of neurons can fire at once, then increasing usage will cause an increase in energy consumption and tempurature.

On the phsychological side, I think problem solving and multitasking will increase *up to a point.* above 50% it will probably decrease again as the brain becomes congested (there are not enough routes through the neurons, limiting intelligence)

If you mean how many of our neourological proccess we can consciously control, then an increase in usage will result in exponentially increasing intelligence, as we conciously find solutions for the shortcomings of the brain (i.e, if you can control your neurons, you can have an almost infinite number of parrelel thought proccesses).

Psy-powers? Not impossible. You may be able to read and control minds, if the brain can pick up and send electromagnetic fields from and to other brains. This would also allow mental communication - your brain's near-infinite parralel thought proccesses allow you to decode anything in a matter of seconds (or less), enabling you to map neorons firing into other peoples thoughts.

Controlling physiological procces would also become possible (to a limited extent), as you would be able to control the primitive areas of your brain that are responsibe for reflexes and homeostasis. This would mean you could control anything to do with homeostasis (heart rate, blood pressure, tempurature, metabolism, growth and healing <-- within biogical boundaries)
as well as reflexes (reactions to pain and fear, pupil dilation, heart rate, blood pressure, adrenalin production, etc)

You would develop a photographic memory, as you made sure each memory was carefully stored, and not altered by anything else.

I do not think changing DNA, omnipotence, tele/pyro/kenesis or altering reality would be possible - but the brain is an incredible and mysterious organ, so who knows?

Comment: The thing is, you still use your brain for storage of information. If you start storing tons of information, you have less neurons available to processing, and vice-versa. Storing _some_ bits of information as photographic might be okay.

Comment: you can get around this by storing memories much more efficiently - a bit like compressing files. hopefully this would mean that no more neurons are used than when storing normal memories.

Answer (score 2):

10% is a myth...but I wouldn't be surprised if 'we only consciously control 10% of our brain' is a little more correct.  There are many processes within your brain that are purely subconscious, from digestion to circulation to cell control, etc.  Lets say for a sec '100% usage' refers to the ability to consciously manipulate the bodies functions at a cellular level.  This gives a good list of 'could you...?'s

- Could you tell an artery to constrict and prevent massive blood loss from a wound?
- Could you tell your immune system to stand down when you are presented with an allergen you react to?
- Could you mass coordinate your cells to speed healing and ensure no scarring?
- Could you instruct your skin cells to rearrange (give your face a new look?)
- Could you instruct your body to reenforce itself?  Maybe fuze the ribcage around the heart and thicken the bone to give some additional protection?
- Could you ignore or negate pain or ill feelings?
- Could you tell your stomach to store some partially digested food stuffs for later usage?
- Could you give yourself a certain degree of night vision by rearranging how your eyes work?
- Could you instruct your body to regrow a missing appendage, or even grow one we don't normally possess?
- Could you rearrange your muscle tissue to be denser and used more appropriately for greater effect?
- Could you instruct another body and it's cells to do any of the actions listed above?
- Could you identify a cancer within your own body and instruct your cells to neutralize them (or simply instruct the cancerous cells to hurry up and die already?
- Could you control the release of chemicals such as adrenaline or endorphins?
- Could you grow a second organ for some redundancy?

If you want to take this a step further...lets say the brain is electrically active as it thinks and this electrically active produces magnetic fields (however minor)

- Could you detect basic magnetic changes in anothers mind as they think and could you convert the magnetic messages into what they are thinking? (mind reading)
- Could you use your own thoughts to induce magnetic fields that alter another persons brain functions (mind influence and potentially mind control).

If you want to take it a bit more extreme...your eyes pick up a tremendous amount of information, your limiting factor is your brain processing it.

- Could you alter your brains perception of what inputs your eyes are using?  Could you perceive what you see on a more fundamental level than the sight we currently use?
- Could you manipulate this fundamental level with your thoughts (telekinesis)?
- Could you determine your mind / spirit is separate from the container we call a body and leave it to enter the unknown?

Little bit more spiritual...

- Could you recognize a 'will' or 'being' at a fundamental level that is driving the world around us (pull the mask back and stare into the eyes of god)?

How far off Lucy am I?  For what it's worth, I actually took some of the above from the Tannion series here [http://www.amazon.com/Tannion-The-Series-Volume/dp/1500635308](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1500635308)